# How to open a windowless chrome incognito window from a Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, incognito-mode, windowless

I've been diving 2 days now about how to open a Windowless (invisible, hidden) chrome incognito window from a chrome extension, it seems that chrome api doesn't allow it!!
i want to avoid using tools as Selenium RC.
Any idea?

Comment: are you talking about 'frameless window'?

Comment: The closest possible thing would be a minimized window.

Comment: It would help if you could elaborate on why you need to do this.

Comment: There's no way to hide an window from task bar with currently existing APIs. As workaround, you can open a new window with minimized state by using chrome.tabs.create

Comment: @SunggukLim Yes i found there many limitations in the chrome api (for now)

Comment: @DanielHerr I want exactly to query webpages anonymously from a chrome extension (For Data Mining Studies Project)